# The DateTime Not SavedTo My database, Turned to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with my PDO command
The data that Insterted into Database especially for DATETIME not works well,
No data inserted.

Here is my Database table Screenshot:

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTNCq.png)

[The Wrong Data Inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6qHn.png)

Here is my code

```
 public function NewDepo($array){

    if(isset($array)){
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `depo` (`depo_id`, `depo_trx`, `depo_address`, `depo_total`, `depo_status`, `depo_date`, `depo_end`) VALUES (NULL, :trx, :add, :total, 1, :tanggal, :ending)");
        $tanggal = time();
        $ending = strtotime('+1 day', $tanggal);                                     
        $stmt->bindparam(":trx", $array['trx']); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":add", $array['address']); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":total", $array['total']); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":tanggal", $tanggal); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":ending", $ending); 
        $stmt->execute();   
        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }   
}
public function NewPayout($array){

    if(isset($array)){
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `depo` (`depo_id`, `depo_trx`, `depo_address`, `depo_total`, `depo_status`, `depo_date`, `depo_end`) VALUES (NULL, :trx, :add, :total, 2, :tanggal, :ending)");
        $tanggal = time();
        $ending = strtotime('+1 day', $tanggal);                                           
        $stmt->bindparam(":trx", $array['trx']); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":add", $array['address']); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":total", $array['total']); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":tanggal", $tanggal); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":ending", $ending); 
        $stmt->execute();   
        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return true;
    }else{
```

Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

By using `strtotime()` it will give you the output as Unix Timestamp. But the `datetime` column requires in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format

So try this,

```
$tanggal = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Will give you 2018-04-07 13:00:00
$ending = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($tanggal))); // Will give you 2018-04-08 13:00:00
```

**Note:**

- 'H' for 24hr format
- 'h' for 12hr format

Comment: Thank you sir, its solved and date recorded correctly into database. But when I want to show it in My page, its still show 1970-01-01 00:33:38 .. Here is the code                 echo '<td><span class="time" style="display: none;">'.$row['depo_date'].'</span>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$row['depo_date']).'</td>';

Comment: Yes! It echo out what is already stored inside the database. Try this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['depo_date']));` Change Y-m-d H:i:s into any format you like, eg: `Y-m-d` or `H:i:s` or `d-m-Y` .

Comment: Thank you so much sir,, You are awesome.. I am still beginner :)

Comment: Glad to help you :) If you find my answer helpful. Please mark it as accepted. Good luck! Click on the checkmark under the post, on the left. (It's right below the up-down vote buttons).

Answer (score -1):

Your datetime format is incorrect. It should be `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`. Try this:

```
<?php

// incorrect
$tanggal = time();
$ending = strtotime('+1 day', $tanggal);
var_dump([$tanggal, $ending]);

// correct
$tanggal = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ending = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($tanggal)));
var_dump([$tanggal, $ending]);
```

http://schoolaf.com/4openRe7Az

Comment: Thank you sir, its solved and date recorded correctly into database. But when I want to show it in My page, its still show 1970-01-01 00:33:38 .. Please check my response in bottom of page.. I showed the code there. :)